# How do I create a function which adds an additional random string to an array in Swift UI

Tags: arrays, swiftui, swiftui-list

Below is the code I have used. I have been trying to display the menuItems List and then create a button which adds an additional random string (from the menuItems Array) to the menuItems list.

At the moment this code only adds an additional button called "add" every time I click the button "add" - none of the list items are being displayed.

I would be expecting a list such as follows:
"Sushi"
"Nigiri"
"soso"
"SeaWeed"
"Boiled Rice"
(Random word)"Nigiri"

struct MenuList: View {

```
@State var menuItems = ["Sushi","Nigiri","soso","SeaWeed","Boiled Rice"]


var body: some View {
    List(menuItems, id: \.self) {string in
        
        
        HStack{
            
            
            Button(action: {
                let RandomAddition = menuItems[Int.random(in: 0...6)]
                self.menuItems.append(RandomAddition)
                
            }) {
                Text("Add")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(.bottom,10.0)
                    
                    
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

```
    //randomize the menu item
    
    
    
    
    




struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MenuList()
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Move your `Button` outside of the `List`. 2) Inside the `List`, display each element (notice how you're not using `string` at all?) 3) Make your data truly `Identifiable` instead of using `\.self`

Comment: Also give a look to [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) to understand Identity in SwiftUI